# What is the difference between src and tgt in nn.Transformer for PyTorch?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

From the docs it says to create a transformer model like this:

```
transformer_model = nn.Transformer(nhead=16, num_encoder_layers=12)
src = torch.rand((10, 32, 512))
tgt = torch.rand((20, 32, 512)) # What is tgt??
out = transformer_model(src, tgt)
```

What is tgt mean't to be? Should tgt be the same as the src?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transformer structure is of two components, the encoder and the decoder. The src is the input to encoder and the tgt is the input to decoder.

For example doing a machine translation task that translates English sentence to French, the src is english sequence ids and tgt is french sequence ids.

Comment: But if I know what the French sentence is already why would I want to use a transformer? I just want to do transformer_model(["Some", "sentence", "here"]) and it outputs another sequence of [0.123, 0.239, 0.189] for example which is the French output. What is this French sequence that I need? If I already know the French sequence why would I need the transformer in the first place.

Comment: You need the french sentence to train the model. In inference step you dont know the french, so the english sentence is send to the encoder, and firstly input <sos> to decoder, the model predict the first french word <w1>. And then in the second inference step, you input <sos> <w1> it gives your the second french word w2, and so on.... Until you get <eos> or it reaches the max  sequence length you want. Highly recommend [this tutorial](http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/) if you haven't read it.